# Why does connecting using an ssh key fail with one host name but work with others?

Tags: ssh, hostname

Trying to use an ssh key to a server which has different host names works with some host names, but not with others?

Is there some reason why ssh would work that way?

E.g. say hostname1.com and hostname2.com point to IP address 1.1.1.1.

using

- `ssh -i ~/.ssh/keyname user@hostname1.com` works,
- `ssh -i ~/.ssh/keyname user@hostname2.com` doesn't.
- `ssh -i ~/.ssh/keyname 1.1.1.1` works.

Another interesting point is when I try to use `ssh-copy-id` to send the public key again via `hostname2.com`, `ssh-copy-id` is able to login and discover that the public key is already present in the `authorized_keys` file without my having to provide the password for the connection which means that there is a difference between `ssh` and `ssh-copy-id` which causes `ssh` to prompt for the password.

Comment: Have you tried hostname2 before it was properly created, and not cleaned your DNS caches?  What happens if you instead use hostname2.com. ? How does the output of `dig ANY hostname1.com` and 2 differ?

Comment: You must have error messages when things don't work, can you add those to you question?

Comment: As above noted, make sure that the resolved IP in the verbose log (`ssh -vvv hostname1.com` is really the same as the one for `hostname2.com`. Secondly, check the verbose log, what is actually going on with the key. The last thing is error log (possibly in `DEBUG3` loglevel), which should tell you why the key was accepted or rejected.

Comment: What are your known host settings on client and server?

Comment: Do you have rules in `~/.ssh/config` that apply to one of the hosts but not the other? As requested, please post the full transcript of `ssh -vvv …` for both hosts (with consistent anonymization).

Comment: @Rui, Jakuje, Nils - The host names are all in /etc/hosts and the `ping` to the right IP address.

Comment: @Gilles suggestion was correct. There was a `~/.ssh/config` file that restricted the combination of host and user to 
`PreferredAuthentications keyboard-interactive,password`. I must have put it there years ago for some reason and had forgotten about it.